# Raven/Sentry logging itself causing maximum recursion depth reached error

Tags: python, django, raven

I have configured Raven 2.0.2 on Django 1.4 using following logging configuration:

```
'handlers': {
    ...
    'sentry': {
        'level':'INFO',
        'class': 'raven.contrib.django.handlers.SentryHandler',
    },
},

'loggers': {
    '' : {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'handlers': ['sentry'],
    },
    'django' : {
        'handlers': ['console-error', 'sentry'],
        'propagate': False,
        'level': 'DEBUG'
    },
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': [],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True,
    },
}
```

Logging for "django" logger works well. For the root level logger, if I try to log an ERROR level message, it goes through. However when I try to log an INFO level message, I get the following error:

```
Top level Sentry exception caught - failed creating log record
Configuring Raven for host: http://1e437dc0d8e347f2b655246d25aa3544:59b1969faf0b4f2e85a823fba93d058a@dev.project.com:9000:/3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dev/env/project/lib/python2.6/site-packages/raven/handlers/logging.py", line 59, in emit
    return self._emit(record)
  File "/home/dev/env/project/lib/python2.6/site-packages/raven/contrib/django/handlers.py", line 32, in _emit
    return super(SentryHandler, self)._emit(record, request=request)
  File "/home/dev/env/project/lib/python2.6/site-packages/raven/handlers/logging.py", line 126, in _emit
    return self.client.capture('Message', message=record.msg, params=record.args,
  File "/home/dev/env/project/lib/python2.6/site-packages/raven/contrib/django/models.py", line 49, in <lambda>
    __getattr__ = lambda x, o: getattr(get_client(), o)
  File "/home/dev/env/project/lib/python2.6/site-packages/raven/contrib/django/models.py", line 133, in get_client
    instance = getattr(__import__(module, {}, {}, class_name), class_name)(**options)
  File "/home/dev/env/project/lib/python2.6/site-packages/raven/base.py", line 152, in __init__
    self.logger.info(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1056, in info
    self._log(INFO, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1172, in _log
    record = self.makeRecord(self.name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func, extra)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1147, in makeRecord
    rv = LogRecord(name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 252, in __init__
    self.levelname = getLevelName(level)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when I had an newer version of raven pointing to a older version of sentry.

Make sure your raven is the right raven for the sentry instance you are running.